# Linear combination of Laplace eigenfunctions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Let's consider Laplace eigenvalue problem
\begin{eqnarray}
-\Delta u = \kappa u\text{ on }\Omega,\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0 \text{ on }\partial\Omega,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary.

It is well known that the eigenfunction $e_{0}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\kappa_{0}=0$ is constant and any other eigenfunction $e_{j}$, $j>0$ change the sign on the domain $\Omega$.

**My question: Is any linear combination of these eigenfunctions $e_{j}$ changing the sign too?**

I was unable to find the answer in usual PDE and functional analysis related books and I did not find a way to prove this myself. I would be very grateful for a reference or hint how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Delta$ is self-adjoint, the eigenfunctions $e_j$ can be taken to be orthogonal; so any linear combination $f = \sum_{j>0} a_j e_j$ satisfies $$\int_\Omega f = \sum_{j>0} a_j \int_\Omega e_j = C\sum_{j>0} a_j \langle e_j, e_0 \rangle_{L^2} = 0$$ since $e_0$ is constant. (Here $C$ is just the constant such that $Ce_0(x) = 1.$) Thus $f$ must change sign unless it is identically zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the integral, but the ortoghonality was the missing idea. I'm wondering if the same could be proven in the case of Dirichlet boundary conditions. There is eigenfunction instead of constant. Would you have any idea?